# Error Installing Ionic On Windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-7, npm, ionic-framework

I have node, npm, and cordova installed on a Windows 7 box.  However, when I run

```
npm install -g ionic
```

I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\me>npm install -g ionic
loadRequestedDeps → after ▌ ╢███████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
Assertion failed: ctx->mode_ != NONE && "already finalized", file src\node_zlib.cc, line 147


C:\Users\me>node -v
v0.12.5

C:\Users\me>npm -v
3.0.0

C:\Users\me>cordova -v
5.1.1
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try using a stable version of npm, instead of 3.0 which is still beta as of this writing?

Comment: I downgraded npm to 2.12 and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded Node to version 0.10.38 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall existing Node.js
2. Download node.js version v4.2.1 from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.2.1/
3. install
4. open CMD Run `npm install -g cordova ionic`

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it might be a ssl error, try:

```
nam cache clean
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

And then try running with debug mode:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic -ddd
```

If not working, see [THIS](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

else: install node-lts